# vhdl operator "and" is ambigous

Tags: vhdl

My synthesis tool does not support VHDL2008 fully and I would like to use a code line of the type: "a <= and bit_vector;" which basically means that a='1' if all bits in bit_vector are '1' and '0' otherwise. (a is std_logic and bit_vector is std_logic_vector).

So I created a little package with my own "and" function to add this onto my VHDL:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package common_pkg is
  function "and" (L: std_logic_vector) return std_logic; -- And all bits in a vector

end package common_pkg;

package body common_pkg is
  function "and" (L: std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
    variable result : std_logic := '1';
  begin
    for i in 0 to L'length - 1 loop
      result := result and L(i);
    end loop;
    return result;
  end function;

end package body;
```

However, when compiling this I get the following errors:

```
** Error: c:\Repo\src\My_test.vhd(127): Operator "and" is ambiguous.
   Feasible operators are:
  (explicit) std_logic_1164."and"[STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR return STD_ULOGIC] at vhdl_src/ieee/stdlogic.vhd(140)
  (explicit) common_pkg."and"[STD_LOGIC_VECTOR return STD_LOGIC] at c:\Repo\src\common_pkg.vhd(23)
** Error: c:\Repo\src\My_test.vhd(127): Type error resolving prefix expression "and" as type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_ULOGIC.
```

I can't figure out how to get around this. I can rename my function to "my_and" but that is not really what I want... Is there anyone out there who has done something similar to this before and would be able to explain the problem and prehaps point me in the right direction?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the first feasible operator (in std_logic_1164) appears to be the 2008-compliant one you're trying to rewrite.

Comment: The synthesis tool probably supports the unary `and` already, thus the error.  Also, making functions that may collide with existing functions is likely to result in problems, if the same code is used in tools with different levels of VHDL-2008 support, like a simulator and a synthesis tool. Btw. consider writing the loop like `for i in L'range loop` for support of L with any range.

Comment: If you can't get the unary `and` to work consider falling back to the VHDL-2002 `and_reduce()` function from `ieee.reduce_pack` that does the same thing.

Comment: Or simply rename your own function `and_reduce` (which, IMO, also makes it clearer what it does)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers and comments:

If need to use your unary "and" operator on a wide input vector, some tools are not smart enough to map the "and" operator to the proper resources. Especially, if your code is targeting FPGAs, there is a way to use carry-chains to speed up the "and" and "or" computation.

The module [arith_prefix_and](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/arith/arith_prefix_and.vhdl) from [PoC Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) has a generic carry chain description written in VHDL and a device specific instantiation for Xilinx MUXCY primitives to speed up wide "and" operations.

There is also a [arith_prefix_or](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/arith/arith_prefix_or.vhdl) module.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the second version but get the same result. The code above is complete for the common_pkg.vhd part. The other code has the following header:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

library unisim;
use unisim.vcomponents.all;

library common_lib;
use common_lib.common_pkg.all;
```

/Teddy